# TeamCity: labeling VCS (Subversion) with an artifact's file version

Tags: svn, label, teamcity, build-server, continuous-integration

I want to create create a label (tag) in the SVN with a file's version.

I'm already renaming the artifact by getting the file version of the main executable produced by the build. Such as: `MyInstaller-1.2.3.1.exe`. Now I want to create a tag in the SVN called `/tags/1.2.3.1`. I couldn't find a way to set such a thing in the labeling pattern.

Currently my labeling is just "%system.build.number%"

Any idea about how to do this?

*I'm using TeamCity Professional Version 4.5.3 (build 9035)*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As someone mentioned, you can output the build number during the execution of the build script, and teamcity will use that output to label the build. For example, I label my build with the same version that I put into AssemblyInfo.cs. Part of that version (Major, Minor) is actually in the file already, the other part (Build, Revision) gets added during the build.

From my msbuild script:

```
<Target Name="Setup">
    <!-- Version.txt contains the major and minor version numbers, 
         The build number and revision come from environment variables
         in the next step -->
    <Version VersionFile="Version.txt" BuildType="None" RevisionType="None">
        <Output TaskParameter="Major" PropertyName="Major" />
        <Output TaskParameter="Minor" PropertyName="Minor" />
    </Version>

    <!-- If you want to build a release without going through the build
         server, you should define the following 2 environment variables
         when running this build script -->

    <!-- BUILD_NUMBER environment variable supplied by the build server -->
    <CreateProperty
        Value="$(BUILD_NUMBER)">
        <Output
            TaskParameter="Value"
            PropertyName="Build" />
    </CreateProperty>

    <!-- BUILD_VCS_NUMBER environment variable supplied by the build server -->
    <CreateProperty
        Value="$(BUILD_VCS_NUMBER)">
        <Output
            TaskParameter="Value"
            PropertyName="Revision" />
    </CreateProperty>       

    <AssemblyInfo CodeLanguage="CS"  
        OutputFile="Properties\VersionInfo.cs" 
        AssemblyVersion="$(Major).$(Minor).$(Build).$(Revision)" 
        AssemblyFileVersion="$(Major).$(Minor).$(Build).$(Revision)" />

    <!-- Tell the build server what our actual build number is -->
    <Message Text="##teamcity[buildNumber '$(Major).$(Minor).$(Build).$(Revision)']" />
</Target>
```

you just output the version during the build the format is `##teamcity[buildNumber '<buildnum>']`

Comment: I found documentation for the ##teamcity Service Message [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/build-script-interaction-with-teamcity.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Ant, maybe you should get SVNAnt.jar and try [this](http://www.sixfive.co.uk/index.cfm/2007/8/6/How-to-get-the-SVN-revision-number-for-use-in-ANT).

The convention that I've seen for labeling is major.minor.svn (and .build if you're using CI).

Comment: actually I'm using sln2008 runner from TeamCity and also my labelling done by TeamCity as well. All other custom build scripts "shamefully" written as Post-Build script in the VS.NET project.

Comment: What I want really make a tag indicates the actual release version, the version which people downloading and using. I thought it'd be the easiest way to mark it.

Comment: Subversion won't read your mind about major.minor release.  You should build that into your tag name.  That'll be enough of a clue for people, in my opinion.

Comment: Normally TeamCity supports variables but I couldn't find a way to put my own variable, I think that's the only way to tell it to TeamCity. Otherwise as you said I need to do it manually in my post-build scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You can include SVN revision number to your TeamCity build number.
For your build number pattern in Teamcity, use something like  {build.vcs.number.1} in the build number pattern field.

After that build number will contain actual SVN revision number, and your labeling pattern %system.build.number% will contain it as well.

Hope this helps,
KIR

Comment: I'm trying to label SVN by using the version of an artifact file.

Comment: You can set build number from your build script and pass it to the server. See TeamCity docs for build script interaction with TeamCity.