# Making TeamCity Version Match .NET Assembly Version

Tags: versioning, teamcity, .net-assembly

Right now our assemblies have a version number like 2.0.831.0.  As I understand it, that's major version, minor version, date and build number.  If I make a change and build again on the same day it's 2.0.831.1, 2.0.831.2 etc.

My TeamCity build number format is simply 2.{0} where {0} is an auto incremented number that just goes on forever (2.195, 2.196 etc).

How do I make TeamCity  look exactly like the assembly version?  We want to be able to associate the Change Log with the assembly version so anyone can say assembly version 2.0.831.2 had these changes in these files.

Extra info:
Our build step uses the "Visual Studio (sln)" option instead of "MSBuild" if that matters.
We use Subversion for source control if that matters.
Our TeamCity version is 6.5.1 (build 17834).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041153/teamcity-labeling-vcs-subversion-with-an-artifacts-file-version

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I would recommend you to adopt the [semantic versioning scheme](http://semver.org/) `{major}.{minor}.{patch}` and append a 4th element for the build number `{major}.{minor}.{patch}.{build}`.
This is way more useful as to include the build date into the versioning scheme.

TeamCity 6.5 (you haven't specified a version) has a build feature which could be used to patch the version in the AssemblyInfo.cs during the build. See the documentation for the [AssemblyInfo Patcher](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/AssemblyInfo+Patcher).

[image: AssemblyInfo patcher dialog (TeamCity documentation)]

You could then define the build number format in the way you would like to have in your assembly and use the format for the build itself, as also for the patching feature.

Comment: Comment on ccellar as answer because I haven't got enough reputation to comment. Version string format is:
major.minor[.build[.revision]]
Build number is the 3rd element, not 4th. If AssemblyVersion doesn't have this format then Version class will have incorrect values in Build and Revision properties.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.aspx

Comment: @jbtibor Good point that Microsoft has a different version number scheme, but I would argue that ccellar's scheme makes more sense, and it's the scheme I use. Think about it: the build number will always be unique when using the TeamCity build number, so multiple builds could have the same revision, but it's not possible to have multiple revisions on the same build, which MS's scheme seems to imply.

Comment: You could use the attribute AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute in AssemblyInfo.cs to specify the semver-version (this attribute will allow you to specify any string as version). This value could then be picked up and used by the build process. I like the idea that it is up to the developer, before committing a change to decide the version information for the thing that he/she checks in.

Answer (score 6):

One solution is to use the MSBuild runner, and write an MSBuild script which reads the version information from the AssemblyInfo file, sets the TeamCity build version to that value whilst running the build, then increments the build number part of that version, and writes the value back to the AssemblyInfo.

This isn't particularly trivial, as you need to have an understanding of writing custom MSBuild scripts, and you will likely need to use some of the community tasks etc to read/write the version information.

We also use the concept of a global AssemblyInfo file, which all of our assemblies reference (using Add Link in VS), and thus we only need to update the one file during the build.

There is an excellent article [here](http://fromthedevtrenches.blogspot.com/2009/11/continuous-integration-from-theory-to.html), which describes doing common CI tasks with MSBuild. He is using CruiseControl.NET, but much of it still applies. If you are running TeamCity 6.5 though, I would look into using its build features exclusively, as this will be much easier to maintain than a custom MSBuild script.

Comment: This all makes sense.  Are there any tutorials for accomplishing this?  I've never worked with MSBuild before.  Do you have any specific examples?